# return nodejs script output to python

Tags: python, node.js

I am trying to execute a nodejs script with python program and get the return output.

b.js

```
data : {
 "1":[],
 "2":[],
 "3":[],
 "4":[],
 "5":[],
 "6":[],
 "7":[],
 "8":[],
 "9":[],
 "10":[],
 "11":[{"id":"1","domain":"www.xxxxx.com","keywords":"白银交易平台","type":"Type1","time":["11","14","15","18"]}]
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```

a.py

```
if response.exitcode == 0:
  print(response.stdout)
else:
  sys.stderr.write(response.stderr)


b'{"1":[],"2":[],"3":[],"4":[],"5":[],"6":[],"7":[],"8":[],"9":[],"10":[],"11":[{"id":"1","domain":"www.xxxx.com","keywords":"\xe7\x99\xbd\xe9\x93\xb6\xe4\xba\xa4\xe6\x98\x93\xe5\xb9\xb3\xe5\x8f\xb0","type":"Type1","time":["11","14","15","18"]}]}\n'
```

From official docs of naked, response.stdout is returned NakedObject. How can I convert the returned NakedObject to python dictionary ?

Comment: If security is not a concern then have you tried `eval`? `eval(response.stdout)`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to use `json module`.

**Ex:**

```
d = b'{"1":[],"2":[],"3":[],"4":[],"5":[],"6":[],"7":[],"8":[],"9":[],"10":[],"11":[{"id":"1","domain":"www.xxxx.com","keywords":"\xe7\x99\xbd\xe9\x93\xb6\xe4\xba\xa4\xe6\x98\x93\xe5\xb9\xb3\xe5\x8f\xb0","type":"Type1","time":["11","14","15","18"]}]}'
import json
print(json.loads(d))
```

**Output:**

```
{u'11': [{u'keywords': u'\u767d\u94f6\u4ea4\u6613\u5e73\u53f0', u'domain': u'www.xxxx.com', u'type': u'Type1', u'id': u'1', u'time': [u'11', u'14', u'15', u'18']}], u'10': [], u'1': [], u'3': [], u'2': [], u'5': [], u'4': [], u'7': [], u'6': [], u'9': [], u'8': []}
```

Comment: oh, sorry. I forgot there is line break at the end of the object
b'{"1":[],"2":[],"3":[],"4":[],"5":[],"6":[],"7":[],"8":[],"9":[],"10":[],"11":[{"id":"1","domain":"www.xxxx.com","keywords":"\xe7\x99\xbd\xe9\x93\xb6\xe4\xba\xa4\xe6\x98\x93\xe5\xb9\xb3\xe5\x8f\xb0","type":"Type1","time":["11","14","15","18"]}]}\n'

and then it gives me an error : 
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @Ekoar. That should not be a problem.